# OpenMCT - Creating plugins with custom views

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to create a plugin with a custom view. I copied the SimpleVuePlugin from the OpenMCT's repository examples folder but got an error that I can't use import statements outside a module. So based on how the default plugins are written I changed the code to this:

```
define(["vue", "./HelloWorld.vue"], function (Vue, HelloWorld) {
function SimpleVuePlugin() {
    return function install(openmct) {
        //here's the same code as in the example file
    }
}
});
```

Now I get an error that define is not defined. The only dependencies I have are express and express-ws (I'm trying to expand the openmct-tutorial project). Can someone please explain how do I create a plugin with a custom view properly?

Comment: Have you found a solution for it?

Comment: Yes I have. I described how I did it in this github issue https://github.com/nasa/openmct/issues/3305

Comment: I just followed all instructions you provided but i am unable to run it. A main.js and its .map files are created when i compile it by using webpack. Then, i run the openMct with "npm start"then it still throws that '"SimpleVuePlugin" is not defined' error. If you have a github repo or similar, could you please provide it to us?

Comment: I do have a repo but unfortunately it's in ESA's private gitlab and I'm pretty sure I can't share it. Maybe you should try creating an issue in openmct's github so someone more competent could help you. I only used openmct once a year ago (for a proof of concept app) so maybe there were some important changes to how it works.

Comment: Do i need to run it via "npx webpack serve" command or "npm start"? Do you remember that? Thank you for your time by the way.

Comment: I had two npm scripts configured in the package.json like this: https://pastebin.com/13ztXSVE and I ran `npm prepare` first and then `npm start`